# In "Forrest Gump", why did Jenny do this thing in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, forrest-gump

In a scene in *Forrest Gump*, Jenny’s old house stands at the end of the dirt road and appears to be deserted. Jenny walks towards the house and stops, staring at it. Forrest walks towards Jenny.

Suddenly, Jenny heaves a rock angrily at the house and throws other things at it:

> JENNY: How could you do this?

She breaks a window. Jenny collapses to the ground and sobs.

Why did Jenny do this thing in this scene?

Comment: Is it weird that when I saw the question title in HNQ I knew immediately exactly which movie and scene? I didn't *think* I watched too many movies...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Jenny suffered from child abuse. Many sources quote or explain that, such as [this fandom](https://forrestgump.fandom.com/wiki/Jenny_Gump) :

> She was raised by her father, a farmer, who physically and sexually abused Jenny and her sisters. Forrest, being simple minded, believed that he was simply a loving father as he was always kissing and touching Jenny and her sisters.

Since the film is told through Forrest's eyes, we only get limited glimpses of this, but, even untold, it's clearly the case. There's a scene where, as a child, she runs away from the house and her father and they (she and Forrest) hide in a field.

> Forrest: "He [Jenny's father] was a very loving man, always kissing and touching her and her sisters.”

When, as an adult, she goes back to this place, she realizes all the pain she suffered because of her father in this very same house. She's overwelmed by emotions and she wishes she could just erase the past by destroying the house.

I like the way [this site](https://forrestgump.fandom.com/wiki/Jenny_Gump) tells the story:

> One day, while on a walk, the pair happen to stumble upon Jenny’s abandoned childhood home. After walking up to the house, Jenny stops and thinks for a bit, reflecting on what had happened to her as a child. Finally, she sees an opportunity to let her anger out and goes for it, feverishly throwing her shoes and rocks at the house — hitting boards and breaking windows. While throwing objects, she says things like, “How could you” and “How dare you” in the process.
>
> It’s suggested that in that moment, Forrest realizes the truth about what Jenny’s father did to her, and that Jenny understands that her upbringing was the catalyst for her painful and rocky years. In her fit, she falls to the ground, sobbing. Forrest quietly walks over and sits nearby, and (in his narration) says, “Sometimes I guess there just aren’t enough rocks.”

Answer (score 0):

Jenny was abused when she was small by her father. It hurt her. She had lots of pent up anger for he father that she never got to release because she was just a little girl and could not defend herself.

The house represents her father.

When she collapses into tears it's because although she was angry, he was the only father she had and she feels cheated.

Comment: Hi Haley, this is, *to me* exactly what (in other words) the accepted answer says. What new does your answer bring?